# 555 Timer IC Simulation in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad, ltspice, 555, spice, ngspice

I am currently designing a circuit in Autodesk Eagle which requires a 555 timer IC. The timer may be any 555 chip, such as an ne555, tlc555, or lm555, or even one of their 556 variants, but the lm555 would be best. I am able to add the device to the circuit just fine, but, as it does not automatically have a model, I am unable to simulate it. After hours of scouring the internet, including but not limited to EE Stack Exchange, I have been unable to find a SPICE, NGSPICE, or LTSPICE model for any of these chips. If anyone could help me to find such a model compatible with Eagle, it would be much appreciated. Also, as this is my first time working with SPICE simulation in Eagle, installation instructions would be further appreciated, but are less important than the model itself.

Comment: LTSpice has a 555 model that I've found adequate although I would be subbing in an HC or HCT model myself.  1 sec I'll check where it is.  There are many 3rd party 555s you can import but I dislike them as they seem to really bog down LTSpice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LTSpice, press F2 to add a component, go into the (MISC)ellaneous directory and choose NE555, "An idealized 555 timer".

I'll see if I can look up how you can import LTS models to eagle, but it may be just as quick for you to research it yourself now that you know where to find a model.